# How to read attributes using XML apache commons configuration

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, apache-commons

I am using Apache Commons Configuration for reading configuration in xml file - `standalone-full-ha.xml` in `Wildfly 8` application server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">
...
...
<profile>
...
...
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
    <datasources>
      <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/TestDB" pool-name="TestDB" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="false" use-ccm="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:ip:port/db-name</connection-url>
      ...
...
  </subsystem>
 </profile>
</server>
```

How to read jndi name `java:/TestDB`and connection url `jdbc:sybase:Tds:ip:port/db-name` from the above xml.

I tried the below but no result is obtained.

```
XMLConfiguration conf = new XMLConfiguration();
((XMLConfiguration) conf).setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
((XMLConfiguration) conf).load("xml file location");
String url = conf.getString("server/profile/subsystem[xmlns= 'urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0']/datasources/datasource/connection-url");
String jndiName = conf.getString("server/profile/subsystem[xmlns= 'urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0']/datasources/datasource[jndi-name]");
```

Can anyone please suggest about how to read jndi name and connection url from the xml using XML apache commons configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFly has a Management API

(https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Management+API+reference)

I would suggest using that API in order to Access the WildFly Configuration 
instead of parsing it 'manually'

Comment: many thanks .. Andre. I need to read datasource information from standalone-full-ha.xml and load it in java context for application use. I went through the link shared and they are based on command line. How can I implement by coding. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: i currently don't have a jboss instance available to test it myself ... but have a look at this link ... http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/monitor-your-jboss-resources-using-the-dmr-api

i think that blog entry should answer your question. it shows how you can build a slsb wich accesses configuration information via the jboss management API. it should be possible to write a standalone application accessing the configuration of a running wildlfy instance as well.

Comment: Many thanks.. Andre. I will look into the link and try that out.

Comment: @sridhar you got the solution i got stuck in the same situation ?